# Strange behavior while running remote powershell execution from Java

Tags: java, powershell

I have a Windows server with WSUS and I am trying to activate some powershell script sitting on that machine.

First of all, the script works when I am trying to activate it via power shell admin shell.
The script looks like this :

```
Enable-PSRemoting
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "*" -Force
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "p@`$`$w0rd" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("1.1.2.3\administrator", $secpasswd)
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName 1.1.2.3 -Credential $creds
Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock {Get-Hotfix}
```

I am using 2 different approach via Java :

```
public static void run2() throws IOException {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder()
                .inheritIO()
                .command("powershell", "invoke-command", 
                "-Computer", "1.1.2.3",
                "-Scriptblock" ,"{&C:\\install-patch-ocomputer.ps1}").start();

        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        proc.getOutputStream().close();

    }


public static void run6() throws IOException {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        Process proc = runtime.exec("powershell Invoke-Command -Computer 1.1.2.3 -Scriptblock {&C:\\install-patch-computer.ps1}");
        try {
            InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  finally {
            reader.close();
            proc.getOutputStream().close();
        }


    }
```

When I am running run2 method I get :

```
[1.1.2.3] Connecting to remote server 1.1.2.3 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client 
cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the 
transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use 
winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more 
information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the
```

When running run6 :
No error, but no output from script as well...

Please help !!!!

Comment: What user identity is used for running the Java code?

Comment: String username = System.getProperty("user.name");              
System.out.println("username = " + username); The output is the user of the machine that the the code is activated on (my user - asi)...

Comment: That means that your code is running in the context of the [Local System account `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-2017#Local_System), and that account is seemingly not authorized to do remoting.

Comment: Thanks...How do I solve the authorization issue?

Comment: The code should work from my development machine (Windows10) and on a Jenkins slave, which is a Ubuntu OS machine...

Comment: I know little about this myself, but whatever account you use must be part of a group that is permitted to talk to the remoting session configuration on the remote computer; hopefully, this will point you in the right direction [`about_Remote_Troubleshooting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-6#how-to-provide-administrator-credentials).